# How to implement BiFunctional function that corresponds to Enum in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, enums, java-8, functional-interface

I have `Java` `enum`:

```
public enum ConflictResolutionStrategy {
    softResolve,
    hardResolve,
}
```

I want to call it like `ConflictResolutionStrategy.hardResolve.apply(case1, case2)`.

Both `case1` and `case2` objects of the same type. `apply` in my case should return nothing.

*The basic idea behind this design. Create `Strategy` design pattern and resolve conflicts based on the set `enum` value.*

I cannot find any similar questions on StackOveflow even simple search gives me tons of similar cases which don't resolve my case directly.

I tried The following:

```
public enum ConflictResolutionStrategy {
    softResolve ((CaseType case1, CaseType case2) -> case1.update(case2)),
    hardResolve,
}
```

This version above doesn't compile.

I tried another solution:

```
public enum ConflictResolutionStrategy {
    softResolve,
    hardResolve {
        public void apply(CaseType case1, CaseType case2) {
            case1.update(case2);
        }
    },
}
```

The second solution, works okay but requires too much code.

Comment: well obviously `softResolve` and `hardResolve` are actually solved in different ways, so you have to override `apply` for them to handle that in different ways... so "too much code" will be required, yes

Comment: @Eugene Since `softResolve` and `hardResolve` are different values and should be treated differently. I do understand that different code should be in both cases. The main point of my question if I can write in `lambda`-like style way the same what works in the last my code sample? I want to reduce noise of the code buy using modern `Java` features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function accepting two parameters and returning nothing is a `BiConsumer`.

Your enum may implement `BiConsumer`:

```
public enum ConflictResolutionStrategy implements BiConsumer<CaseType, CaseType> {
    softResolve ((case1, case2) -> case1.update(case2)),
    hardResolve((case1, case2) -> {/* do something else */});

    private final BiConsumer<CaseType, CaseType> consumer;

    ConflictResolutionStrategy(BiConsumer<CaseType, CaseType> consumer){
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(CaseType case1, CaseType case2) {
        consumer.accept(case1, case2);
    }

}
```

---

Suppose you have a method for processing your cases:

```
public void processCases(Collection<CaseType> cases, BiConsumer<CaseType, CaseType> conflictResolutionStrategy){
    // ...
}
```

Now you can pass in either one of your existing strategies:

```
processCases(cases, ConflictResolutionStrategy.softResolve);
```

or an inline strategy:

```
processCases(cases, (c1, c2) -> { /* do smth here */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like a `BiConsumer` within the enum as :

```
public enum ConflictResolutionStrategy {
    softResolve(CaseType::update), // just for example
    hardResolve((caseType, caseType2) -> {
        caseType.update(caseType2);
    }); // lambda representation

    BiConsumer<CaseType, CaseType> caseTypeBiConsumer;

    ConflictResolutionStrategy(BiConsumer<CaseType, CaseType> caseTypeBiConsumer) {
        this.caseTypeBiConsumer = caseTypeBiConsumer;
    }
}


class CaseType {
    void update(CaseType caseType){}
}
```

Comment: how would you use that btw? provide that example in the question also - and you will see that you are just deferring the same "too much code" to a different place.

Comment: @Eugene agreed that code would have to be written somewhere for sure, in this case, `update` or other such implementation would be the block. Just brought this up to better bind type and relate to the version that OP tried and didn't compile for them.

Comment: @nullpointer This compiles for me but how can I call `BiConsumer` from my `enum`? I try something like `ConflictResolutionStrategy conflictStrategy = ConflictResolutionStrategy.softResolve; conflictStrategy.accept(case1, case2)` but `accept` method not visible. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi It would have to be `conflictStrategy.caseTypeBiConsumer.accept`